# Execute mapped command in vim without hitting return

Tags: vim, keymapping

I use the Voom outliner plugin in vim and mapped a command to :

```
:map <M-o> :VoomToggle markdown
```

The mapping works but when I use it, it just puts the command into the command line of vim. I still have to hit return for execution. How can the command applied automatically without hitting return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the concluding <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the mapping, just as you'd type it.

```
:map <M-o> :VoomToggle markdown<CR>
```

Vim uses a special notation, like in the mapping keys; see `:help key-notation`.

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: thx. I already thoght that there must be a notation, but I didn't find it while looking for it. And thx also for the noremap suggestion